# Box Blur algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This is a challenge from CodeSignal.

For

```
image = [[1, 1, 1], 
         [1, 7, 1], 
         [1, 1, 1]]
```

the output should be `boxBlur(image) = [[1]]`.

To get the value of the middle pixel in the input 3 × 3 square: `(1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 7 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1) = 15 / 9 = 1.66666 = 1`. The border pixels are cropped from the final result.

For

```
image = [[7, 4, 0, 1], 
         [5, 6, 2, 2], 
         [6, 10, 7, 8], 
         [1, 4, 2, 0]]
```

the output should be

```
boxBlur(image) = [[5, 4], 
                  [4, 4]]
```

There are four 3 × 3 squares in the input image, so there should be four integers in the blurred output. To get the first value: `(7 + 4 + 0 + 5 + 6 + 2 + 6 + 10 + 7) = 47 / 9 = 5.2222 = 5`. The other three integers are obtained the same way, then the surrounding integers are cropped from the final result.

Here's my code:

````
function boxBlur(image) {  
    const SQUARE = 3
    const outerArr = []

    for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        const innerArr = []
        
        for (let j = 0; j < image[0].length; j++) {
            if (image[i][j] !== undefined && image[i][j+2] !== undefined && image[i+2]) {
                let sum = 0
                
                for (let k = 0; k < SQUARE; k++) {
                    for (let y = 0; y < SQUARE; y++) {
                        sum += image[i+k][j+y]    
                    }
                }
                innerArr.push(Math.floor(sum/9))                
            }
        }
        if (innerArr.length) outerArr.push(innerArr)
    }
    return outerArr
}
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some suggestions on coding style:

- Your choice in variables is somewhat confusing `i`, `j`? For an algorithm operating on a 2D image, the names `x` and `y` would be better. And `dx`, `dy` for the offsets in the inner loop.
- You defined the width of your kernel as `SQUARE`, yet you hardcode `2` in the expression `image[i][j+2]`.
- Your boundary checks can be more efficient. Why check for `undefined` if you know the exact size of the image? You can loop `i` from `0` to `image.length - SQUARE`, and loop `j` from `0` to `image[0].length - SQUARE` and remove the if statement:

```javascript
for (let i = 0; i < image.length - SQUARE; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < image[0].length - SQUARE; j++) {
        // no if-statement needed anymore
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the naive algorithm works fine for small kernels, but can be done more efficient using a summation map where you first calculate the total sum of all preceding values in a preprocessing step, and then calculate the sum of the pixels in the square using the summation map of the 4 corner points. That way, the algorithm speed becomes independent of the size `SQUARE` of your kernel.

Comment: very helpful. I initially checked for `undefined` as some numbers in the `image` can evaluate to `0`; the if statement would fail then. Regarding your third bullet point, I couldn't really understand it. Could you show me a bit of code?

Comment: @uber Added example code. By reducing the range of the `i` and `j` variables, the inner `k` and `y` loops will never exceed the boundaries so you can remove the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

The code in general is pretty good, so I don't have a lot to suggest, just a handful of pointers.

- As already mentioned, variable naming could be a little better. For example, I'm not sure why your two most inner loops use the variables "k" and "y". "SQUARE" would probably be better named as "SQUARE_SIZE". outerArr and innerArr could be newImage and newRow. etc.
- Four nested loops is quite a lot. You could easily extract the two most inner loops into its own "calcBlurValueAtCoord()" function.
- When checking for out-of-bounds, the `image[i][j] !== undefined` check is doing nothing - `image[i][j]` will never be undefined. In fact, that whole `if()` could be simplified to this: `if (image[i+2]?.[j+2] !== undefined)`

Once you've applied those bullet points, I think your code would be pretty solid.

If you additionally wanted to make the code a little more functional and less procedural (not that you should or shouldn't, it's just a different style), you could replace the for loops with functions such as `.map()` and break out more helper functions.

In the below example, you'll notice that the boxBlur() function is really high-level - just by reading it, you can get an overview of how a box-blur is done: "With each coordinate in the grid, calculate a blur value, then trim the margins". What does it mean to "calculate a blur value"? Just look at that function definition (for blurValueAtCoord()): "Take the average of the surrounding coordinates and floor it" - you get the idea.

```javascript
const boxBlur = grid => trimMargins(
  coordsInGrid(grid)
    .map(coord => blurValueAtCoord(grid, coord))
)

const average = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length

const coordsInGrid = grid => grid.flatMap((row, y) => row.map((_, x) => [x, y]))

const blurValueAtCoord = (grid, coord) => Math.floor(average(getSurroundingValues(grid, coord)))

const trimMargins = grid => grid.slice(1, -1).map(row => row.slice(1, -1))

const getSurroundingValues = (grid, [y, x]) => [
  grid[y-1]?.[x-1], grid[y]?.[x-1], grid[y+1]?.[x-1],
  grid[y-1]?.[x],   grid[y]?.[x],   grid[y+1]?.[x],
  grid[y-1]?.[x+1], grid[y]?.[x+1], grid[y+1]?.[x+1],
].map(x => x ?? 0)
```

Comment: loved the if statement simplification

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without an if statement as suggested by Jason

I removed the if statement, I used dx dy to represent the offset of x and y respectively

I didn't see the need to initiate Square variable to 3, hence I -1 so I can trim the borders

Hope this helps someone

```
function boxBlur(image){

    let blur = [];

    for (let x = 1; x < image.length - 1; x++){
      Let line = [];

      for (let y = 1; x < image[0].length - 1; y++){
         let sum = 0;

            
           //slicing off the borders of the image

           for (let dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++){
             for (let dy = -1; dx <= 1; dy++){
                sum+= image[x + dx][y + dy]
             }
           }
           line.push(Math.floor(sum/9));
       }
       blur.push(line);
    }
    return blur
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but there's very little actual _review_ here. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].